# I want to rewrite a url in .htaccess file

Tags: php, rest, url

I want to rewrite a url in `.htaccess` file. in localhost for `localhost/pdo/connect?id=3` as `localhost/pdo/connect/3` I am using this

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^/connect/([0-9]+)$ connect.php?id=$1 [L].
```

But in connect.php I am getting an error:

> undefined index id in $_Get["id"]

Comment: Please format your question, and in particular the code part, so that it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI} "!connect.php"`

`RewriteRule ^connect/([^/]+).*" "connect.php?id=$1" [L,QSA,PT]`

above rule working as follow.

**www.sitename.com/connect/id**

Comment: its not working. Now also same error i.e I am using $_GET["id"] to get id value from url and it is giving error undefined index id